# Changing Interface Staging Area in ODI using ODI SDK classes

Tags: oracle, etl, data-integration, oracle-data-integrator

Hi I am new to ODI and ODI SDK. I have created some sample mappings using ODI SDK and now I am wondering   if there is a way to change the Staging Area for my interface. Till now I have used default target server as my staging area.

Basically, I want to use **In Memory Engine: Sunopsis  memory engine** and I have searched the OdiInterface class in SDK but I cant find anything related to that.

Please help if anybody knows how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried it directly from the SDK, but I would try this :

- Build a new InterfaceExecutionArea instance using the In Memory Engine as a dataserver http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/apirefs.1111/e17060/oracle/odi/interfaces/interactive/support/execarea/InterfaceExecutionArea.html
- Use the setExecutionArea method on your object to move it in this newly created ExecutionArea http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/apirefs.1111/e17060/oracle/odi/interfaces/interactive/support/execarea/InterfaceElementInExecutionArea.html#setExecutionArea_oracle_odi_interfaces_interactive_support_IExecutionArea_